# How to use Javascript to select an option from “Collapsible Dropdown Listbox” that seems to be autogenerated?

Tags: javascript, applescript, automator

I'm trying to automate filling a form on this nyc healthscreening [webiste](https://healthscreening.schools.nyc/?type=G). The problem is that it seems to autogenerate the list of options for the entry "School or Facility You're Entering" . The options list don’t seem to be laid flat nicely in the page source as I could find in examples on the web, where each option has its own id.

I wonder how can I use javascript (`getElementById` maybe?) to select a particular option (school location in this case) from the list?

Comment: Are you trying to automate this for one particular item in the list or many different items in the list? If just one, which one?

Comment: Just for one, it's "P.S. 452"

Answer (score 0):

Here is some *example* **AppleScript** *code* you may find useful:

```applescript
set targetURL to "https://healthscreening.schools.nyc/?type=G"

set guestIsStudent to true -- true or false
set guestFirstName to "John"
set guestLastName to "Doe"
set guestEmail to "johndoe@example.com"
set schoolFacility to "P.S. 452"
set guestLocationFloor to ""

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:targetURL}
    tell application "System Events" to repeat until exists (buttons of ¬
        UI elements of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
        process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    tell document 1
        if guestIsStudent then
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('guest_isStudent').click();"
        else
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('guest_isVisitor').click();"
        end if
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('guest_first_name').value = '" & guestFirstName & "';"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('guest_last_name').value = '" & guestLastName & "';"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('guest_email').value = '" & guestEmail & "';"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('guest_location_floor').value = '" & guestLocationFloor & "';"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down')[0].click();"
        delay 1
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "P.S. "
            delay 0.5
            keystroke "452"
            delay 0.5
            key code 125 -- Down Arrow
            delay 0.5
            key code 36 -- Enter
        end tell
        if (do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('k-textbox')[0].value;") is equal to schoolFacility then
            --  # Click the Fill Out Daily Screening button.
            do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary mt-2 btn-lg')[0].click();"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```